# Why is it wrong to cast Object[] array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, generics

I'm very new to generic programming in Java.

I don't understand why arrays of generic type can't be created.

```
T[] a = new T[size]; //why does this give an error?
```

If generic type means that the generic placeholder `T`will be replaced by a class name during run-time, what prevents us from creating an array having generic references?

After a bit of searching, I found a workaround

```
T[] a = (T[])new Object[size];   //I don't get how this works?
```

Although I found a solution, I still fail to understand what prevents from creating a generic array.
Suppose I create a function that returns an Object array.

```
public Object[] foo(){
        return new Object[12];
}
```

And then make the call

```
String[] a = (String[])foo();
```

gives a `ClassCastException` . But why?
Doesn't it look similar to first line of code where I cast Object array into T array?

```
 T[] a = (T[])new Object[size];
```

If this went without a glitch why didn't that?

Comment: You asked a total of  six questions in one :)

Comment: @SURESH  ATTA I felt that they were all related :/

Comment: @Djack: generic type **do not mean** "that the generic placeholder T will be replaced by a class name during run-time". It is replaced **before** run-time by `Object`. Java generics works differently from C++ templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the point is to look at it the other way around.  You cannot do `(String[]) new Object[10]`; because an `Object` array is *not* a `String` array.  Because

```
String[] array = new String[10];
array[0] = "foo";
String foo = array[0];
```

is fine, but

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object[10];
objectArray[0] = 10;
String[] stringArray = (String[]) objectArray;
String foo = stringArray[0];
```

...is trying to assign an `Integer` to a `String`, which shouldn't be allowed in the first place.  So this code fails when you cast the `Object[]` to a `String[]`.  That code *has* to throw a `ClassCastException` somewhere.

This is all the same for Java even before generics were invented in the first place.  Accept all that *first*.  *Then* move on to generics.

Now, the way Java generics are *implemented* means that when you compile the code, `T` is silently rewritten to `Object`.  So `T[] array = (T[]) new Object[10]` is silently allowed, because it actually gets rewritten to `Object[] array = new Object[10]`.  But as soon as you take it out, things go wrong.  For example,

```
private static <T> T[] newArray() {
   return (T[]) new Object[10];
}
```

if you call `String[] array = newArray()`, you'll get a `ClassCastException` at the call site, not within `newArray()`.  This is why Java gives you a warning at `(T[]) new Object[10]`, and that warning may well lead to a real `ClassCastException` later on.

Generally speaking, don't mix arrays and generics.  The way around all this is to use a `List` properly.

Comment: Your answer was helpful but if the `T` is rewritten to `Object` then when I create an instance what happens? Like `Hello<String> = new Hello<>()` Does the `T[]` remain `Object[]` only and not become `String[]`?

Comment: Yes.  Yes, the `T[]` remains `Object[]` only, and then when you try to get it out as a `String[]` you get a `ClassCastException`.  Java will insert typecasts anywhere you pull out generics and assign them to an actual type.

Comment: So if at compile time the generic placeholders are rewritten to `Object` then saying `T[] = new T[size]` should not be a problem because it will be converted into `Object[] = new Object[size]`. But yet the compiler gives an error?

Comment: No, you can't write `new T[size]` at all, because the compiler was written to force you to create arrays only with their real actual type, so you can write `(T[]) new Object[n]`, but then you get a warning.  The Java compiler doesn't let you pretend that `new T[]` is a real thing you can do.

Comment: This is exactly what is haunting me for long long time. I would be very happy if you clarify this. ".. because the compiler was written to force you to create arrays only with their real actual type" What is the very need to write the compiler this way? What could go wrong in converting T[size] to Object[size].

Comment: @vvtx that's covered in the second part of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to note when dealing with arrays.

First, arrays are considered to be **covariant**; that is, a typed array will maintain its inheritance chain.  So, an `Integer[]` is an `Object[]` in the same fashion that an `Integer` is an `Object`.

This is why your last example fails.  You want to cast an `Object[]` to a `String[]` through `foo`:

```
String[] a = (String[])foo();
```

An `Object[]` will never be a `String[]` since an `Object` isn't a `String` (but the opposite will always be true).

Second, arrays and generics don't mix all that well.  Generics are considered to be **invariant**; that is, they would not maintain their inheritance chains.  A `List<Integer>` is *not* considered to be the same as a `List<Object>`.

As to why your particular example fails, this is due to **type erasure** at compile time.  Arrays are required to know their concrete type at compile time, and without this information, they cannot be instantiated.  Since generics don't store that information, you can't instantiate a generic array in the same way you would instantiate a non-generic array.

That is to say, you **must** use the cast form:

```
T[] a = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

[You can read a bit more about generic arrays in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/530289/1079354), as it covers most of the main points that you would need to know when dealing with them.

Comment: You said: "...required to know their concrete type at compile time, and without this information, they cannot be instantiated" But instantiation does not happen at Compile time but the runtime and at run time we do know the concrete type for type parameter and then at runtime it can then instantiate the array of that concrete type. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @vvtx:  Yeah, you're wrong.  You can't reify a generic parameter.  Arrays require reifiability.

Comment: Yes I learned that Arrays require reifiability, but that is required while instantiation, i.e. at run time, and at run time you know your concrete type. You said: "You can't reify a generic parameter" but  when the parameter type is non array it is reified to Object type in byecode, i.e. T e  is replaced to Object e after compilation then what is stopping T[] e to Object[] e?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays know their type at runtime. A `String[]` knows it is an array of `String`s.

In contrast to this, generic type parameters are erased at runtime, so a `List<String>` at runtime is just a `List`.

Since type parameters `T` are not available at runtime `new T[10]` (which doesn't compile) could not possibly create a true `T[]`.

It is not true that

```
T[] a = (T[])new Object[size];
```

can't throw an exception. It can. Louis Wasserman's example shows that it can cause an exception at the call site, but that line can also throw an exception directly. For example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo();
}

static <T extends Number> void foo() {
    T[] array = (T[]) new Object[42];
}
```

Here, the lower bound of `T` is `Number`, so at runtime, it is attempted to cast an `Object[]` to a `Number[]`, which throws a `ClassCastException`.

You can create a `T[]` if you have a `Class<T>` object `clazz`, using for example

```
Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
```